What's the translation of buddy taping in French?
https://www.mountsinai.org/health-library/selfcare-instructions/broken-toe-self-care:

Buddy taping: Wrap tape around the injured toe and the toe next to it. This helps keep your toe stable. Place a small wad of cotton between your toes to prevent tissues.

What's the translation of buddy taping in French? Google Translate and Linguee weren't helpful.


Image source: https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQQ9QUr7wbRIr1yvz1Hqs7tRTFs7C2w6G0BFQ&s

En France on parle communément de strapping d'orteil pour le fait d'attacher un orteil à l'autre en cas de fracture, mais le terme plus technique et cependant compris de tous est  « fixation en tandem ».

En cas de fracture de l’orteil, le traitement consiste à fixer l’orteil fracturé à l’orteil adjacent (fixation en tandem) pendant plusieurs semaines. (Doctissimo)

Si on regarde la version en anglais de Toe Fractures dans le Manuel Merck on a :

Treatment usually consists of taping the fractured toe to the toe next to it (called buddy taping)...

et la page en français correspondante Fracture des orteils:

Le traitement consiste généralement à strapper l’orteil fracturé à son voisin (fixation en tandem)...


Je te plussoie - ces termes semblent être dans le même registre que "buddy strapping".

@Frank :) non seulement du même registre mais correspondance dans les termes :  strapping/fixation, buddy/tandem

Syndactylie ou syndactylisation, selon le Grand dictionnaire terminologique de l’Office québécois de la langue française.

Oui, mais bon, même si les deux racines grecques adéquates s'y trouvent correctement, l'expression est inutilisable en dehors d'un contexte médical, alors que "buddy taping", c'est plutôt des mots courants. Si tu sors d'une rando où tu t'es fais mal aux pieds et que tu racontes: "j'ai du me faire une petite syndactylie vite fait", on va te regarder bizarre...

Ne dit-on pas simplement "une attelle aux doigts de pieds"?

@Frank D'accord avec toi, en France le terme n'est pas employé par le vulgum pecus, il n'y a que les médecins qui emploient le terme,  d'autant plus que syndactylie étant aussi une maladie, ça prête à confusion.
